# How can I split string using custom regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, match

```
let myString = "Hello 'How are you' foo bar abc 'Strings are cool' d b s ;12gh gh76;"

const myRegEx = / \w+ "\w* +" | ;\w +; +/g  // This what i have figured but its not working :(

const splitedString = myString.split(myRegEx)

console.log(splitedString)
```

Expected Output:

`["Hello", "How are you", "foo", "bar", abc, "Strings are cool", "d", "b", "s", "12gh-gh76"]`

Let me try to explain more:

First off all split whole string on basis of a space " ", except string inside `''` or `;;`, like:

`"Hello  'Yo what's up'"` --> `["Hello", "Yo-what's-up"]` (Notice Here's extra `'` in what`'`s, so handle that too.)

Then if string is inside `;;` then concat (I believe that's the right name) it with `-` like:
`Hello ;hi there;`  -->  `["Hello", "hi-there"]`

and in the end return a array of all the formatting done... as expected output.

Comment: What should happen to phrases like `'a ;b c; d'` and  `;a 'b c' d;`?

Comment: Oh never thought that , my needs are just splitting whole string on basis of spaces, but not spliting the words inside `''` and concating words which are inside `;;` with `-`,

Because the string will always be in this formate i provied..

Few Example:

`"Hey 'hwy hi bye' ;lol 123; "`
`"Wow ;what a great catch; 'yay that was funny' 'ooh that's realy bad' 'oh my god'"`
`"Realy 'you wanna do that?' ;no i don't; ;yes you do; 'I said, no!'"`

Hopefully this is helpfull...

Comment: You can use `matchAll` instead of split, with the following regex: [`([';]).+?\1|\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/GflfeN/1), and then iterate through result, remove wrapping quotes, and change `;a b;` to `a-b` interdependently.

Comment: @markalex Can you just have a look at [this snippet](https://runjs.co/s/Rlr3$asd9) and tell where it's a good approach or not, if not , can you please hlep otimise it and i am not able to convert `;abc def; -> abc-def` please have a look at that part too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matchAll` instead of split, to find match content of quotes, pair of semicolons or separate words with regex [`([';]).+?\1|\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/GflfeN/1).

And later remove wrapping and replace spaces where needed.

```js
const myRegEx = new RegExp(/([';]).+?\1|\w+/gm)

const message = "Hello 'How are you' foo bar abc 'Strings are cool' d b s ;12gh gh76; ;a 'b c' d; 'a ;b c; d' d" // Try edit me

const matches = Array.from(message.matchAll(myRegEx))

const finalResult = matches.map(str => {
  const value = str.shift()
  if(value.match(/^;.*;$/))
    return value.substring(1, value.length-1).replaceAll(' ', '-')
  else if(value.match(/^'.*'$/))
    return value.substring(1, value.length-1)
  else
    return value
})

// Log to console
console.log(finalResult)
```

Notice, that this solution works on the assumption, that wrapper (quotes and semicolons) are not nested.

If you need to account nested wrappers, regex is not best tool for the job, since you'll need to check "parenthesis"-balance, and while it's possible with regex, where easier ways to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much but the last  second string in output array is not formatted, my needs are not that much, but just for curiosity `a ;b c; d` -->  `a b-c d`

Comment: @AkT01, as I pointed out in answer "nesting" is not trivial to solve. (Also, you stated in the comment that it wouldn't happen). I believe best general solution for this would be to split resulting string by `;`, replace spaces with `-` in every even-indexed element, and then rejoin it back.

Comment: @markalex You mean *odd*-indexed? `b c` has an index of 1 as the second element.

Comment: @InSync, yes, of course. May bad.

Comment: @markalex yeah, I didn't read that, My bad, but i would like to tell that in my scenerio 

`'abc ; def ghi; jkl'` and `;a 'b c' d;` 

these two cases are never needed to handle :-0

Answer (score 2):

One needs an at least two folded approach

First one has to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) any semicolon delimited range by replacing each of its whitespace sequence(s) with a single dash which would look like ...

```
`Hello 'how\\'re you feeling' foo bar abc 'Strings are cool' d b s ;12gh gh76;`
  .replace(/;([^;]*);/g, (match, capture) => capture.replace(/\s+/g, '-'))
```

... where the regex is ... [`/;([^;]*);/g`](https://regex101.com/r/ZShVPL/2) ... and the result will be ...

```
"Hello 'how\\'re you feeling' foo bar abc 'Strings are cool' d b s 12gh-gh76"
```

Secondly one needs to come up with a [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)ting regex which can handle both, splitting at any whitespace (sequence) but only if it is not part of a single quotes enclosed substring. The latter needs to be captured in order to be preserved while splitting. The above example code then continues to look like ...

```
`Hello 'how\\'re you feeling' foo bar abc 'Strings are cool' d b s ;12gh gh76;`
  .replace(/;([^;]*);/g, (match, capture) => capture.replace(/\s+/g, '-'))
  .split(/'(.*?(?<!\\))'|\s+/)
```

... where the splitting regex is ... [`/'(.*?(?<!\\))'|\s+/`](https://regex101.com/r/ZShVPL/1) ... and the resulting array does contain a lot of *empty* values like empty string values and undefined values. Thus the `split` task needs to be accompanied by a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based cleanup task ...

```
`Hello 'how\\'re you feeling' foo bar abc 'Strings are cool' d b s ;12gh gh76;`
  .replace(/;([^;]*);/g, (match, capture) => capture.replace(/\s+/g, '-'))
  .split(/'(.*?(?<!\\))'|\s+/)
  .reduce((result, item) => item && result.concat(item) || result, [])
```

The next provided example code just does proof the explanation of the above approach ...

```js
const sampleString =
  `Hello 'how\\'re you feeling' foo bar abc 'Strings are cool' d b s ;12gh gh76;`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/ZShVPL/1]
const regXSplitAlternation = /'(.*?(?<!\\))'|\s+/;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/ZShVPL/2]
const regXSemicolonRange = /;([^;]*);/g

console.log(
  sampleString
    // first ... 
    // ... replace any semicolon delimited range by replacing 
    //     each of its whitespace sequence(s) with a single dash.
    .replace(regXSemicolonRange, (match, capture) => capture.replace(/\s+/g, '-'))
);
console.log(
  sampleString
    .replace(regXSemicolonRange, (match, capture) => capture.replace(/\s+/g, '-'))
    // second ...
    // ... split the intermediate replacement string at
    //      - either a single quoted character sequence (capturing it)
    //      - or a whitespace (sequence) (not capturing the latter).
    .split(regXSplitAlternation)
    // ... and third ... do omit any empty (undefined, empty string) item.
    .reduce((result, item) => item && result.concat(item) || result, [])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Seems pretty pro level stuff to me, ;_; I am and intermediate guy and also i have to understand it as much as possibe beacuse i have to fit it inside my typescript code, because i am actually using typescript for my project, my scenerio seemed javascripty to me, so I thought i should ask it as javascript problem.

Comment: @AkT01 ... of cause it's a combined JavaScript / regex problem, and in order to be comprehensive the not that high-level approach comes in digestable pieces like **replace**, **split** and **reduce**, each with its own explanation and JS documentation and regex playground links.

Answer (score 1):

You might capture the parts that you want to reformat and then after process them by checking for the capture group number:

```
'([^']+(?:'[^\s'][^']*)*)'|;([^;]+);|\S+
```

The pattern matches:

- `'` Match `'`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^']+'` match 1+ chars other than `'` followed by `'`
  - `(?:'[^\s'][^']*)*` Optionally repeat a single non whitespace char other than `'` followed by optional chars other than `'`
- `)` Close group
- `'` Match `'`
- `|` Or
- `;([^;]+);` Match from `;...;` and capture in **group 2** what is inside
- `|` Or
- `\S+` Match 1+ whitspace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhUvbk/1)

```js
const regex = /'([^']+(?:'[^\s'][^']*)*)'|;([^;]+);|\S+/g;
const s = `Hello  'Yo what's up'`;
[
  `Hello 'Yo what's up'`,
  `Hello 'How are you' foo bar abc 'Strings are cool' d b s ;12gh gh76;`,
  `Hello ;hi there;`
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(
    Array.from(
      s.matchAll(regex), m => {
        if (m[1]) return m[1]
        else if (m[2]) return m[2].replace(/\s+/g, "-");
        else return m[0];
      }
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Words inside `''` are not supposed to be concated with `-`. But very good answer, thank you so much :)

Comment: @AkT01 Ow yes, let me change that.

Comment: Pretty good explaination as well, but sorry I have accepted answer from other guy, beacuse he was the first to comment and both answeres are pretty good and he also modified my provided function, and i am honestly confused what to accept, so finnaly i have picked that guys answer, but you have done great job, hopefully you understand, thank you so much :)

Comment: @AkT01 You are doing the right thing, no worries! :-)